# Hi my Wordpress theme not supportimg pagination.How can i add custom pagination in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display only 5 posts in my blog page. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not play with WP PageNavi plugin and make a custom editing.

Comment: Use this plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Comment: If the code not working i will try pluginThanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi nikita pagination is a default property of wordpress.
Refer Wordpress Codex
So please Remove the query_posts part from the template files (index.php, category.php).

```
    <?php 
// query to set the posts per page to 5
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged );
query_posts($args); ?>
```

And add the query for your home and category pages back in your theme's **functions.php** file:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  // do not alter the query on wp-admin pages and only alter it if it's the main query
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){

    // alter the query for the home and category pages 

    if(is_home()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 5);
    }

    if(is_category()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 5);
    }

  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

Maybe your problem will solve...